# I/O monitoring on Kubernetes / CoreOS nodes

Tags: io, load, kubernetes, coreos, prometheus

I have a Kubernetes cluster. Provisioned with `kops`, running on `CoreOS` workers. From time to time I see a significant load spikes, that correlate with I/O spikes reported in Prometheus from `node_disk_io_time_ms` metric. The thing is, I seem to be unable to use any metric to pinpoint where this I/O workload actually originates from. Metrics like `container_fs_*` seem to be useless as I always get zero values for actual containers, and any data only for whole node.

Any hints on how can I approach the issue of locating what is to be blamed for I/O load in kube cluster / coreos node very welcome

Answer (score 2):

If you are using nginx ingress you can configure it with

```
enable-vts-status: "true"
```

This will give you a bunch of prometheus metrics for each pod that has on ingress. The metric names start with `nginx_upstream_`

In case it is the cronjob creating the spikes, install node-exporter daemonset and check the metrics `container_fs_`